# template xxx.ftl not found in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using `Eclipse LUNA` and create a java project to send SMS to the mobile with some text. It is working fine, now I convert the java project into `Maven` based project by using **configure to maven project** it is converted and `POM.XML` is also added. But when I am trying to run the project it gives error.

Error is:

```
SMS Sending Failed

 Template "xxx.ftl" not found `
```

can you please help to me i tried a lot but it can't solve it.

Comment: Where is your `xxx.ftl` file located?

Comment: In the project it self i have the folder templates with in that i place my .ftl files

Answer (score 0):

Maven references to templates like '.ftl' separately as resources. So you need to add the path to resources in POM.xml

You can point the path to root of your java if you have your templates distributed in many packages and don't change the paths given in your project.

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/java</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Or you can point it to the templates folder you have, as mentioned by,

```
<project>
 ...
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
 ...
</project>
```

Note: You will have to refer to the templates w.r.t. to the path you mention in the resource directory.
Eg. If your templates directory is com/foo/bar/templates and you set the resource directory to be src/main/java/com/foo, you will have to refer to your ftl as /bar/templates/example.ftl